# How to declare a nullable guid as an optional parameter for a C# CLR stored procedure with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, guid, optional-parameters

I'm writing a C# stored procedure which is deployed on SQL Server 2008 R2 (so .Net 3.5) and want to declare an optional parameter as a nullable guid.  Here's what I tried first:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void spCalcPerc(
     SqlGuid pID
    , SqlGuid sID = DBNull.Value
    )
```

This failed with the compile time error:

> *Default parameter value for 'sID' must be a compile-time constant*

which is because `DBNull.Value` is not a constant, which is a pain.

So I tried changing the declaration to:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void spCalcPerc(
     SqlGuid pID
    , Guid? sID = null
    )
```

This compiles but now I get this deployment error:

> *Deploy error : Could not create a type for parameter System.Nullable*

Trying:

```
, SqlGuid sID = null
```

Gives this compile time error:

> *A value of type '< null >' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid'*

So feeling rather stuck I resorted to this:

```
, SqlGuid sID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

Which I didn't want to do as testing for that string in the code feels like a kludge.  However that doesn't work either as I get this compile error:

> *A value of type 'string' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'System.Guid'*

Gah, 4 different approaches and none of them work.  *sigh*

Would appreciate your thoughts or a push in the right direction please.

Comment: Have you tried just "Guid? sID", without the =null?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
, SqlGuid sID = New Guid()
```

You can use

```
if (sID == Guid.Empty)
```

To check if it is has not been assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with just passing in Nulls for the values you want defaulted?
Granted this may not work in every situation.
Sometimes you may want to know if the actual value is indeed Null, and therefore avoid using the default.
If this is the case, then  I would resort to adding an additional "*Default*" parameter.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void MySproc(SqlGuid pID, SqlGuid sID, SqlBoolean UseDefault_sID)
{
    sID = (UseDefault_sID == SqlBoolean.True && sID == SqlGuid.Null)
        ? SomeDefaultPIDValue : sID;
}
```

This saves on having to write additional "*wrapper*" sprocs to take in optional parameters with default values that then call your CLR sproc.

To use the Default-Value when Null pass in: UseDefault_pID = 1
To keep the Actual-Value when Null pass in: UseDefault_pID = 0

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void spCalcPerc(
     SqlGuid pID
    , SqlGuid sID
    )
```

And then register it manually in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCalcPerc]
    @pID [uniqueidentifier],
    @sID [uniqueidentifier] = null
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlServerProject3].[StoredProcedures].[spCalcPerc]
```

And then you can use the [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid.isnull.aspx) property to test whether `sID` is in fact null:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(sID.IsNull.ToString());
```

I'm not aware of a way to declare the default in your C# code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but did you try

```
Guid.Empty
```

?

Comment: Would produce the same error as the first: "Default parameter value for 'sID' must be a compile-time constant" - since `Guid.Empty` isn't a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, this is because C#2.0 doesn't support optional parameters.

One workaround may be to wrap the .NET stored procedures in regular T-SQL stored procedures that do accept default paramters.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcWrapper
(
    @TestIntWrapperParam int = null
)
AS
EXEC TestProc @TestInt = @TestIntWrapperParam
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for null as follows.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void spCalcPerc(SqlGuid pID)
{
    // check for null or set default
    Guid refId = pID.IsNull ? Guid.NewGuid() : pID.Value;
```